# Cannot get my navigation bar to line up with my main body

Tags: html, css

So I have to make a web page for school using HTML and CSS.  Everything appears to be 100% fine when I view it in my code preview but once I put it on my server the navigation bar is no longer aligned with my main body

Here is my CSS

```
body {
    background-color:#2AA890
}

nav {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 45px;
    list-style: none;
}

li a:link, li a:visited, li.selected {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    line-height: 3em;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 3px #ba0000 solid;
}

li:last-child a {
    width: 110px;
    border-right: 0px #6e2525 solid;
}

.head {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px
}

.box {
    margin-left: 185;
    width: 882;
    height: 450;
    background-color: #acacac;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px 10px 10px 10px
}

.pic1 {
    width:900px;
}

.pic1 img {
    float:right;
}

.pic1 p {
    text-indent: 40px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px; 
    margin-right:400px;
}

.head {
    padding: 25px 0px 0px 45px  
}

.pic1 p {
    padding: 0px 5px 10px 8px
}

.pic1 img{
    padding: 30px 20px 20px 10px;
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Supplies.html">Supplies</a></li>
      <li><a href="Step_1.html">Step 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="Step_2.html">Step 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="Step_3.html">Step 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="Step_4.html">Step 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="Step_5.html">Step 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="Step_6.html">Step 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="pic1">
      <img src="drew_brophy.jpg" alt="Art" title="Drew Brophy" width="480" height="374">
      <div class="head">
        <h2>How to Paint a Surfboard</h2>
      </div>
      <p>The surfboard, one of the most fun toys around.  There is just one problem with it.  The majority of them are plane white.  There is no color and adding some stickers isn't a true way to express yourself!  With a little time and some common items from your garage or hardware, you can make it so much better.  You don't have to be a great artist or have lots of money to truly make that board your own.  This site is a simple guide with some tips and tricks for painting your surfboard.  When the waves aren't breaking and your looking at that board in the corner of your room, take some time and change it up! </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you viewing it in?

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, please add 'px' for height, width, height for 'box' class.
For Nav UL, remove the margin.

Sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrUqK/

```
margin-left: 185px
width: 882px
height: 450px
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please review the margin in your ul and in the .box class set an equal margin-left.

```
ul {
  margin:45px 0px;
}
.box {
  margin-left:0px;
}
```

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/